# Swap LHS's (or equivalently RHS's) of two rules in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

Assume I have a list of rules, each of the form $a_i \rightarrow b_i$.  What is the best way, for some $i$ and $j$, to swap $a_i$ with $a_j$ (or equivalently, $b_i$ with $b_j$).

Currently, I have this very inelegant thing:

```
swapRules[rules_List, i_Integer?Positive, j_Integer?Positive] := 
  Module[{iLhs = rules[[i]] /. (lhs_ -> rhs_) :> lhs, 
    iRhs = rules[[i]] /. (lhs_ -> rhs_) :> rhs, 
    jLhs = rules[[j]] /. (lhs_ -> rhs_) :> lhs, 
    jRhs = rules[[j]] /. (lhs_ -> rhs_) :> rhs},
   ReplacePart[rules, {i -> (iLhs -> jRhs), j -> (jLhs -> iRhs)}]
   ];
```

Comment: The order of application alters the result, so swapping the LHS is not always equivalent to swap the RHS

Comment: @belisariusisforth: Indeed -- I forgot to point out that it was "equivalent" merely in what I am/was doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
swapRulesA[rules_List, i_Integer?Positive, j_Integer?Positive] := 
 ReplacePart[rules, {{i, 1} -> rules[[j, 1]], {j, 1} -> rules[[i, 1]]}]
```

or

```
swapRulesB[rules_List, i_Integer?Positive, j_Integer?Positive] := 
 ReplacePart[rules, {{i, 2} -> rules[[j, 2]], {j, 2} -> rules[[i, 2]]}]
```

Comment: `swapRulesA[{a -> b, c -> a, b -> c}, 1, 2]`

Comment: @belisariusisforth Thanks for pointing that out. Please see my edit, such cases should be covered now.

Comment: Can't check right now, but  it looks OK. +1

Comment: Thank you so much.  I should have remembered that `Part` works on arbitrary expressions and not only on lists.  The perks of regular language structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
swapRules[r1_List, i_, j_, k_: 1] := Module[{r = r1},
                                     r[[{i, j}, k]] = r[[{j, i}, k]]; r]

swapRules[{lhs1 -> rhs1, lhs2 -> rhs2, lhs3 -> rhs3}, 1, 2]
(* {lhs2 -> rhs1, lhs1 -> rhs2, lhs3 -> rhs3} *)

swapRules[{lhs1 -> rhs1, lhs2 -> rhs2, lhs3 -> rhs3}, 1, 3, 2]
(* {lhs1 -> rhs3, lhs2 -> rhs2, lhs3 -> rhs1} *)
```